# How can i track down how is these files created

Tags: linux, centos

How can i track down what command or how is all these files being created? 
My server is always occupied 100% of its storage. and I've checked my another instances which don't have these files.

```
52.7 GiB [##########] sys1.sys
23.3 GiB [#### ] sys5.sys
14.9 GiB [## ] sys4.sys
9.2 GiB [# ] sys.sys
8.4 GiB [# ] sys8.sys
8.4 GiB [# ] sys3.sys
8.4 GiB [# ] sys2.sys
3.7 GiB [ ] sys7.sys
1.9 GiB [ ] sys6.sys
```

I got this from ncpu.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    9892426060 Apr 28 09:00 sys.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   56626016256 Apr 28 09:04 sys1.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    9007920576 May  3 06:32 sys2.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    9007920576 May  3 06:32 sys3.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   16010560576 May  3 06:34 sys4.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   25013200576 May  3 06:35 sys5.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    2005040576 May  3 06:36 sys6.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    4005280576 May  3 14:11 sys7.sys
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    9007920576 May  3 14:12 sys8.sys
```

Is there a way to validate my install of Centos of find out the files not belong to etc?

Comment: Welcome to unix stackexchange. Where are the files in question on the OS ? You have a server that is running out of disk space, have you checked what is running ? How is the CPU usage ? Have you checked for active network connections ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do several things:

1. Check what is run by `cron` of `root` user. This is usually the place to check
2. Use `file` utility to understand what kind of files they are: `file sys.sys`
3. Check your daemons/services. There you can find some software which can create the files (check the documentation of the software). I have in my practice software which create empty huge files and use them as buffers.
4. Activate `audit` subsystem and add monitoring of this particular directory. Then remove the files and wait till they appear again and check the audit logs to see which process create them.
5. Search in entire OS for file which contain string `sys.sys` (can take serious amount of time.